# Full Screen Flash help

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am writing a tiny tiny thing for a museum that is just basically a flash flip book, there are next and back buttons at the bottom of the page. I am having an issue making it FULL SCREEN. I really have no idea how to do this. I am 100% new to flash but basically this is going to be a swf that runs and needs to just take up 100% of the screen. Thanks for the help, Aaron

also im in action script 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `fscommand("fullscreen","true");`

Make sure you hide the keyboard though, because visitors will be able to just press Esc and exit :)

Comment: yeah, its all hidden,  i put in fscommand, but when i launch the swf it still shows like the menu bar

Comment: This is gonna be a horrible question but in which....object... do i place these fscommand lines?